Why did this merge conflict occur?
In
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts:
It states:
"Conflicts generally arise when two people have changed the same lines in a file, or if one developer deleted a file while another developer was modifying it."
In the following sequences of Git operations, different lines (line 3 and line) of file readme was modified in two branches (master-dev5 and master-dev6). Conflict arose when
merging master-dev6 to master or merging master to master-dev6. But according to the above statement, there should be no conflict since the change was not made to the same line?
$ git checkout -b master-dev5 master
$ git checkout -b master-dev6 master
$ git checkout master-dev5
$ cat readme
begin
added by dev1, added by dev2
added by dev3, added by dev4
$ echo "added by dev5">>readme
$ cat readme
begin
added by dev1, added by dev2
added by dev3, added by dev4
added by dev5
$ git add readme
$ git commit -m "dev5 add something on line4"
$ git checkout master-dev6
$ cat readme
begin
added by dev1, added by dev2
added by dev3, added by dev4
$ vim readme
$ cat readme
begin
added by dev1, added by dev2
added by dev3, added by dev4, added by dev6
$ git add readme
$ git commit -m "dev6 add something on line3"
$ git checkout master
$ cat readme
begin
added by dev1, added by dev2
added by dev3, added by dev4
$ git merge master-dev5
Updating 3b87e7c..28e91e1
Fast-forward
 readme | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git merge master-dev6
Auto-merging readme
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in readme
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ cat readme
begin
added by dev1, added by dev2
<<<<<<< HEAD
added by dev3, added by dev4
added by dev5
=======
added by dev3, added by dev4, added by dev6
>>>>>>> master-dev6

$ git merge --abort
$ cat readme
begin
added by dev1, added by dev2
added by dev3, added by dev4
added by dev5
$ git checkout master-dev6
$ git merge master
Auto-merging readme
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in readme
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ cat readme
begin
added by dev1, added by dev2
<<<<<<< HEAD
added by dev3, added by dev4, added by dev6
=======
added by dev3, added by dev4
added by dev5
>>>>>>> master


Adjacent lines count as "the same line".
